# Segmentation fault at end of the function

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, free, dynamic-arrays

When my function finishes the last for loop, it returns a segfault. I don't know why. Here's my code.

```
void initArray(int a[], int n){
    int i, j;
    a = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    for(j = n-1; j >= 0; j--){
        int num1 = rand() % (j+1); // generates a random number from 0 to n
        int container2 = a[j];
        a[j] = a[num1];
    a[num1] = container2;
    }
    // Array checking purposes
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
        printf("%i ", a[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(a);
}
```

It is supposed to create a dynamic array then randomize the numbers inside the array. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: [Your code works perfectly fine](https://ideone.com/sORMkz). You aren't trying to access `a` outside `initArray`, are you?

Comment: @Baka Baka The function does not make sense because the value of its parameter a is not used in the function void initArray(int a[], int n){
    //...
    a = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int)); Its seems the segmentation fault occurs in the caller after the function call when the passed argument is used. So you should show how the function and its argument are used in the caller

Comment: Outside the function, I have initialized `int n, *a` and called the function as `initArray(a, n);`

Answer (score 0):

> It returns a segfault

The array  `int a[]` in

```
void initArray(int a[], int n){
```

cannot be used outside the function `initArray`. The created memory is destroyed by `free(a)`;

Change it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int * initArray(int n){
    int i, j;

    int *a =  malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    for(j = n-1; j >= 0; j--){

        int num1 = rand() % (j+1); // generates a random number from 0 to n
        int container2 = a[j];

        a[j] = a[num1];

        a[num1] = container2;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return a;  
} 

int main(void)
{
    int *a;
    int k;
    int n = 5;

    a = initArray(n);

    // Array checking purposes
    for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
        printf("%i ", a[k]);
    }

    free(a);
    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
5 2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the reason of the segmentation fault is using the argument passed to the function after the function call in the caller.

The function does not make sense because the value of its first argument is not used and is overwritten in the beginning of the function

```
void initArray(int a[], int n){
    int i, j;
    a = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    //...
```

Take into account that the original argument passed to the function is not changed because the function deals with a copy of the value of the function argument.

And using `free`

```
free(a);
```

contradicts the function name.

It seems you need to declare the function like

```
void initArray(int **a, int n){
    //...
    *a = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        ( *a )[i] = i+1;
    }
    //...
```

and you need to remove the call of `free`.

Also it seems you should write

```
int num1 = rand() % n;
```

instead of

```
int num1 = rand() % (j+1);
```

Comment: This helped. I fixed it and I brought the allocation out of my function and put it in main. Thanks.

Comment: Since we don't know what the calling code looks like, we can"t say what happens. The function shown does nothing with the parameter a.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I advice at first to read comments of the author of the question instead of writing your silly comment and down-voting the correct answer.

Comment: If I remember it, I will upvote again when I can, because the OP found your code useful. We will never know what the actual error was, which is alright.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Thje reason of the error is enough clear. The OP passes the pointer by value thinking that the original pointer will be also changed. And he by mistake uses free.